# Handle disconnections using Android NSD

Tags: java, android, service, wifi, service-discovery

I was wondering how to handle disconnections using the [Network Service Discovery](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html)

I register the Service on the Network :

```
NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo = new NsdServiceInfo();
serviceInfo.setPort(Network.SERVICE_PORT);
serviceInfo.setServiceName(Network.SERVICE_NAME);
serviceInfo.setServiceType(Network.SERVICE_TYPE);

Network.nsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, Network.registrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
    public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Network.INTENT_SERVICE_REGISTERED);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
    }

    public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
    }

    public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
    }
});
```

Simple... It works. All other devices now can "see it" on the network.

**The problem** occurs when I disable and then re-enable the wifi.
The others devices can not discover it anymore.

I tried to unregister the Service, and then re-register it. Without success. The only way to make it work is by closing the app and restarting it.

Comment: Hi @Denis, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @NimilaHiranya No... I unfortunately had to reinvent the wheel and to program a network discovery service from the scratch. (By pinging all computers on the network).